# How can i add an action button into a collectionView's section cell?

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, ios10, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I have a photos collection view with different section header with different items but i want to add an action button into the last cell of a section which will take a photo and will be added the photo to the section cell and only last cell of the section will be contain the action button .I
attached a similar photos of screen in the link below.

Comment: What have you done till now? Please explain what you have added, so that we can help you out.

Comment: You said you attached something but I don't see it. I see an edit history where the link was fixed (along with grammar) but then reverted.

Answer (score 1):

@User,

Add action(.touchUpInside) on button in header for all section and while performing events you can detect that if that section is last than perform task otherwise return.

e.g

#### Add these calls inside view for header in section

```
section.tempButton.tag = indexPath.section
section.tempButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(performTask), for: .touchUpInside)
```

then it will call the selector when **touched**

```
@objc func performTask(sender:UIButton){
      if sender.tag == lastSection{
         //perform task  
      }
}
```